# Material size button size not changeable (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI for React.

[image]

This is the UI that I have so far, but I want to `Submit` button to have the same height as the `Select` component.

I tried to give `height: 100%` to the button

```
    <Button
      style={{ height: "100%", width: "30%" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
    >
      Submit
    </Button>
```

But this doesn't really change the height.

This is the link for the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-nvcxk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you have a requirement for potentially scaling the height, but generally input heights are fixed, so there's really nothing wrong with specifying it:

```
<Button
  style={{ "min-height": "56px", width: "30%" }}
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

Sometimes there's no need to really overcomplicate things :D

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For material-ui component custom styles

First, make sure you find the related official document well [material-ui button-api](https://material-ui.com/api/button/)

Open dev mode in your browser and you may find your button have the classes below like this

```
<a class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root Connect(RawComponent)-margin-38 MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-fullWidth" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" href="..." >
  <span class="MuiButton-label">
    Your Button Name
  </span>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root">
  </span>
</a>
```

Notice that there are some classes refer to document

```
MuiButton-root // => Notice the `root` here
```

All you need to do is to add some styles to those classes. But how? There are many ways. All listed here also in document [material-ui style solution](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#why-use-material-uis-styling-solution)

In your situation, choose one of the solutions and it will be done.

[image: Edit focused-newton-37qer]